VDD and VDDA microcontroller
I have an STM32F030F4 microcontroller that has VDD and VDDA pins that I can use a jumper to turn on and off the 3.3V power supply. The GND pin is also connected directly to the microcontroller. I use an LM317 voltage regulator to supply the necessary voltage to the microcontroller, which provides 3.3V.
The problem I have is that without connecting the 3.3V jumper to the microcontroller, I have a voltage of 1V on the VDD and VDDA pins, which changes slightly when I change the voltage with potentiometer. I have not been able to find the cause of this, and on the other side of the jumper I have 3.3V, which is used to power the microcontroller when the jumper is connected.
In addition, GND is connected to the microcontroller and the necessary decoupling capacitors are in place. I have checked all traces and there are no short circuits.


A schematic would help. If you have any connection to any pin you will reverse power the MCU via internal protection diodes. 1 V sounds like there is some resistor in the way, so maybe a pull-up for I²C or something along those lines.

In particular, what is connected to the other pins of the chip? It sounds like you're powering it up through the I/O protection diodes.

I am not sure why no one is saying this, but it is a long standing rule to not drive any pins on a processor (on any logic chip) above the voltage of the power pins. To do so could create a lock up condition and your processor may not boot up as expected. W/o a schematic and better explanation it is difficult to comment. Assuming you are trying to conserve power ... look for processors that can go into very low current hibernation (some go as low as micro Amps!) rather than removing the voltage from their power pins.

Please look at the schematic that I put below

Please [edit] your question rather than posting additional information as an "answer".

(Since the schematic has now been supplied by the OP, I'm reopening the question - it seems clear enough now. || For those site members who tried to help by suggesting possible answers in comments, while waiting for the schematic, please consider writing actual answers. Remember comments should be considered temporary & have limited allowed uses which do not include writing answers, TY)

You can not pull IO pins to 3.3V if MCU supplies are disconnected.
At least one pin, KEY1 on PA7 is not 5V tolerant, so it will push current from 3.3V supply into the MCU and out from the VDD pin.
The other KEY pins are 5V tolerant.

Thank you for your response. The reason you explained was correct.

Some GPIO (KEY#) pins are still connected to the 3V3 rail through resistors (R5, R6, R8). Also the NRST pin is kept connected to the 3V3 rail through R4 resistor.
The GPIOs may have protection (clamping) diodes connected to the supply rails (VDD/VDDA and VSS):

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
It's obvious that multiple internal blocks are connected to VDD pin. Because a voltage is applied to the GPIO through a resistor whilst the VDD is floating, anything that is supplied from VDD may try to draw some current. That current will drop a voltage across the resistor (R5, R6 or R8 in your schematic) so you'll see a non-zero voltage at VDD pin. This is called "powering from GPIO" and should be avoided.
Plus, the absolute maximum ratings are usually given w.r.t. VDD and VSS rails. For example, the maximum GPIO voltage could be VDD + 0.2V. In your case, VDD is floating but you are applying at least 2V to a GPIO which means trying to operate outside the device limits.

Yeah. First thing catching my attention was NRST, right away since that kind of thing was exactly what I expected. Them I chose to look down at the answers. Saw you caught it.. So I'm done looking. +1

Thank you very much for your response! I hadn't noticed that detail before. Your explanation was the best, and it solved the problem.

I'm not sure your 3.3V from the keys is causing the problem. The STM32F030F4  has 5V-tolerant inputs which typically use a different input structure than simple diodes to Vdd.
However there is an internal pullup resistor on the NRST pin which is connected to 3.3V in your schematic. It's possible that if you remove R4 the issue will disappear. There's still an internal pullup so it should not be necessary. The internal resistor is switchable via an internal p-channel transistor, but that switch may not block in reverse.

Thank you for your response. The reason you explained was correct.
